# setState in react function not updating in promise method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, async-await

Im using reactjs and know it pretty well such as the fundamentals. However, I have been doing research on this weird behavior and havent been able to find the culprit. Maybe one of you react elites have an idea lol. So I am using a stateful component that has the following state object

```
this.state = {
  buttonVisible: false,
};
```

So to show the button and change the state, I am doing so in a promise

```
handleSubmit = async (e) => {

const { status } = this.props;

     e.preventDefault();


     await verifyForm().then((data) => {
       const submissionSuccess = status === 'SUCCESSFUL_SUBMISSION';
       this.setState({
         buttonVisible: submissionSuccess
       });
       actions.showNotification(data);
     }).catch(err => actions.showNotification(err));
   };
```

And in the render method:

This is the button that has the onClick handler that should set the buttonVisible state to true.

```
           <Button
              fullWidth
              onClick={this.handleSubmit}
              type="submit"
              variant="contained"
              color="primary">Submit 
            </Button>
```

After I click the button with the onClick handler, it should render the following button if this.state.buttonVisible is true.

```
{ this.state.buttonVisible &&
                  <Button
                    onClick={this.handleShowModal}
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary">
                    Proceed
                  </Button>
                }
```

But it is not rendering the button. So I console logged the this.state.buttonVisible info and it is still false.

I know that the method is not returning any error because I can see that the form is verified successfully on my end, also, it is not going to the catch block, but the .then block.
I think it has something to do with the handleSubmit handler. But not sure what it is. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where does the `status` variable come from? Are you sure it gets set to `'SUCCESSFUL_SUBMISSION'`?

Comment: Yep, its basically coming from redux. I am mapping the redux state to props, and the 'status' is basically 'SUCCESSFUL_SUBMISSION'. I also see it in the console log there that this is the status @ScottyJamison

Comment: Note that if you're destructuring status in the outer function, then you're going to be using the value of status at the time it was destructured. Try using this.props.status directly instead.

Comment: There is no need to use `async-await`, if you are using `.then` and `.catch`

Comment: can you make a sandbox and let's see where is the problem. You can use codesandbox.io

Comment: @KennyQuach Is `status` set in  redux during `verifyForm` call? If that's the case, the value of `status` won't change in the current event cycle. You will have to grab the `status` from `data`, or trigger your existing code in the next event loop (e.g. setTimeout).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` returns resolved value of Promise and not a Promise to which `then` can be attached. You can modify your code:

```
    ...
   try{
       const data = await verifyForm();
       const submissionSuccess = status === 'SUCCESSFUL_SUBMISSION';
       this.setState({
             buttonVisible: submissionSuccess
           });
       actions.showNotification(data);

    }catch(err){
     actions.showNotification(err)
   }
```

Comment: However, I see that the successful notification is being called, which is below the this.setState method in the then block of my code

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous and operates in batch. Do you want  to call `showNotification` after `buttonVisible` is set ?

Comment: Nope, just need it to be called so that this.state.buttonVisible is true upon successful submission. So it is in the .then block.

Comment: In that case, I assume `actions.showNotification(data);` is setting some state using `redux`. So you can use lifecycle `componentDidUpdate`.Inside, compare `notification` related states and set button visibility.
Ref:https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate.